# WPF : Can I Animate Grid.Background in code?

Tags: c#, wpf

My Code is like this.
I want to create Grid dynamically.
creation is success, but I can't animate it's color.
What is my mistake?

```
        Grid[] grid = new Grid[99];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            grid[i] = new Grid();
            grid[i].Width = grid[i].Height = 100;
            grid[i].Background = Brushes.WhiteSmoke;

            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            ColorAnimation ca = new ColorAnimation(Colors.DarkTurquoise, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(ca, grid[i]);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("Fill.Color"));
            sb.Children.Add(ca);
            grid[i].MouseEnter += delegate(object sender2, MouseEventArgs e2) {
                sb.Begin(this);
            };

            stackMain.Children.Add(grid[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

WPF `Grid` has no `Fill` property you will have to use `Background`

```
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("Background.Color"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what sa_ddam has said, you would also have to *create* a Brush, since the built-in brushes (like `Brushes.WhiteSmoke` in your example) can't be animated.

```
grid[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke);
...

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("Background.Color"));
```

---

It might also save some code if you omit the Storyboard and run the animation directly:

```
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke);
grid[i].Background = brush;

var ca = new ColorAnimation(Colors.DarkTurquoise, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));

grid[i].MouseEnter +=
    (o, e) => brush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ca);
```